# Boostrap CSS - Show a collection of items sizely

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a list of objects will be displayed into my View. Well, I want to display 3 or 4 per row. When I display 3, I use `class="span4"`, and when I display 4, I use `class="span3"`. Although, when the div overflow the `span12`, the next object will be displayed is in a wrong size, like this:

[image: Wrong display]

Well, I want the fourth div display exactly above the first div.
My code is like this:

```
<div class="span2">MENU</div>
<div class="span10 container-fluid">
    <div id="products" class="row-fluid"> 
    @foreach (Product product in Model)
    {
        <div class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>@product.Name</h3>  
            <h6>@product.Description</h6>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle that reproduces my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Kiwanax/utPsh/

Can someone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: What's your CSS so far?

Comment: Right now, just a few lines to border my items. Nothing relevant yet. The biggest problem is with the items alignment with Bootstrap.

Comment: @Kiwanax can you post the code that dynamically generates your items?

Comment: @snumpy, see mine answer below.

Comment: @Kiwanax please show the for loop that is generating the content.  I think you'll need to use a modulus function to decide when to begin and end rows, but I can't be sure until you post the code that generates your items

Comment: @snumpy I thought about this function also. I think is the "better" way to solve it, but diselegant.

Comment: @Kiwanax the function I posted below is less elegant in code, but will give you a far more robust appearance to the user.  Boostrap is fantastic, but you have to work within its limits (max span of 12) if you want to enjoy its benefits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the bootstrap grid system was designed for use with lists... I'd try to go with divs instead.

```
<div id="products" class="row-fluid">      
    <div class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
        <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
        <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
    </div>

    <!--etc-->

</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Also, you will have undesirable results if your spans add up to 16.  So I'd stick with 3 `span4`s or 4 `span3`s.

**EDIT:**
You may run into more issues by adding a border to your grid spans, as it will increase the width of each element by two (assuming a border-width of 1px).  So I'd put your border on a nested div inside the grid span div:

```
<div id="products" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
            <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--etc-->

</div>
```

**EDIT:**

The Bootstrap grid system is not designed to handle more than 12 span, so you will have to change how you generate the html to account for it.

I see you're using MVC.  Assuming you're using Razor, you will want to do something along these lines:

```
<div id="products">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    @{int counter = 0;}
    @foreach (var toy in toys) 
    {
        if (counter > 0 && counter % 3 == 0) <!--check if it's the beginning of the next row-->
        { 
            @:</div> <!--terminate previous row-->
            @:<div class="row-fluid"> <!--start a new row-->
        }
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="item-bordered text-center">
                <h3>toy.Name</h3>  
                <h6>toy.Description</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        counter++;
    }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @snumpy, but the result remains the same. My items are generated dinamically, so I can't get Yenn's approach. Any idea?

Comment: @Kiwanax post the code that generates the items, and we'll get it figured out

Comment: the code just will create that div `<div class="item-bordered text-center">...</div>` a lot of times. Nothing relevant. The problem is align the generated content. I've created the dynamic code using C#/ASP.NET MVC, so, for understading purposes, it's just a `for` loop that generate that divs above.

Comment: I'll try your approach. I developed something like that here, but I think it's... diselegant, hahaha. Later i'll be back with the results.

Comment: NICE! Your loop logic works nice! Thank you for the tips, @snumpy!

Answer (score 0):

the `span4` class, combined with `row-fluid` is designed to show 3 responsive elements in one row.
to do what you want to do, simply add a new row and put the fourth element in it.

```
<div class="row-fluid">      
    <ul id="products">
        <li class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
            <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
        </li>

        <li class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
            <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
        </li>

        <li class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
            <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <ul id="products">
        <li class="span4 item-bordered text-center">
            <h3>Pelúcias Angry Birds</h3>  
            <h6>As mais lindas pelúcias dos pássaros mais queridos do momento.</h6>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i suggest to use divs instead of li's for a lighter markup

OR you can try to override the margin-left from bootstrap setting it to 0 and give an equivalent margin-right:

```
 .item-bordered {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left:0px !important;
    margin-right:1.4%;
}
```

[**HERE is your updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/utPsh/3/)

Comment: I thought this, but my items will be generated through a collection iteration. So, my problem is align them while they're being generated.

Comment: i've experienced some strange ul/li default alignment like this before. have you tried to simply transform ul/li in divs as i also suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but unlucky it doesn't work. Can you reproduce this code to see what I need?

Comment: i have no working code as you provided none... it will be useful for us to have something to experiment with. a jsFiddle reproducing the problem or a simple url to inspect will make solving your problem easier.

Comment: i udated my answer. it's always easier with some code to work with :)

Comment: Everything lines up, but that removes the margin for every element, basically breaking boostrap's grid layout.  The only way to maintain the boostrap layout is to dynamically create new rows.  See the edit to my answer